# Is there a recent or known issue with the #flurry Data Download?

Tags: flurry, flurry-analytics

Our #flurry App Data Download appears bugged.

We requested raw data for analytics recently Oct, 2rd 2020, but the result was not enough than  our expected data amount. there are only a few raw data. for example we compered Arbitrary period old which got around Sept 11th to  new which got after 5th Oct.

- around Sept 11th data is 16MB
- after Oct 5th data is  18.6kB

Above data is same period and same data choice.

There is few raw data which is reported but also there is enough event counts on the Flurry Analytics. the every data graph is normal.

```
Flurry analytics web site.  --> about 30,000 data 
Exported data    --> about 60 data
```

It's not relate the export file format (CSV, XML, JSON).

It's same result

**Add information 2020.Oct.7th**

I did data download  how to this below.

1. Flurry analytics console login
2. Click the Data Download of Sessions
3. And select application SmartSync(iOS) or SmartSync(Android)
4. Set Event for any period, and CSV or else.

Is this a known issue or recent bug?

If someone know the any tips or correct setting, could you please advice?

Comment: Hi! Can you email support@flurry.com with further details, such as the report ID and which app it was for? We will look into it.

Comment: @FlurryAnalyticsSupport I've just mail more detail on it. please confirm it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is now fixed. Please email support if you have further difficulties.

Comment: Thank you so much Support team !! 
It's very helpful for us. 
Could you tell us What was wrong with  ? 
I want to know if it's our fault or wrong operated.